# declaring and calling PHP object functions with period in name

Tags: php, oop

I'm using an API that returns different values, and I want to dynamically tell my class to run a function with the same name (so i won't need a huge `switch` or `if/else` mess).

1. How can I declare the object method `song.pause`?
2. How can I use the object method `song.pause`?
3. This might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so is there a better way to do this? One alternative i thought of is to always call `str_replace('.','_',$type)` and set functions without the periods. Thoughts?

Example:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    ...
    ...
    $type = "song.pause"; // This value is returned from another API I can't control

    if (property_exists('MyClass', $type)) {
        $success = $this->{$type}(); // ???
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid type: $type);
        exit;
    }


    public function 'song.pause'() { // obviously incorrect :)
          ???
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're generally asking is **not supported**. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.

This also applies to class methods.

As the walkaround, you may follow the way that you suggested yourself:

```
$type = 'song.pause';
$type = str_replace('.', '_', $type);
$this->{$type}(); // will call song_pause()
```

OR use ["dark" magic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call):

```
<?php
// header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

class Test {
    function __call($method, $args){
        // do redirect to proper processing method here
        print_r($method);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        print_r($args);
    }
}

$x = new Test();
$x->{'song.pause'}(1,2,3);
?>
```

Shows:

```
song.pause           // < the method
Array                // < arguments
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

However, the "long" and really transparent way, which I completely agree with, [is suggested by **@scrowler**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25615285/2269749).

Comment: Alright, figured as much. Thanks! Looks like I'll have to get creative.

Answer (score 3):

Given a return of `song.pause`, conceptually `song` should be the class name and `pause` should be the method, consider this possibility:

```
class MyClass {
    protected $classes = array();

    function processResponse($response) {
        // $response example is "song.pause"
        list($class, $method) = explode('.', $response);
        if(!class_exists($class)) {
            // Class doesn't exist
            die("Class name {$class} doesn't exist! Exiting...");
        }

        // Instantiate class
        $this->classes[$class] = new $class();

        if(!method_exists($this->classes[$class], $method)) {
            // Method doesn't exist within specified class
            die("Method name {$method} doesn't exist within {$class}. Exiting...");
        }

        // Call method
        $result = $this->classes[$class]->{$method}();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Your logic implementation would be something like this:

```
class song {
    public function pause() {
        return 'foobar';
    }
}
```

[Here's an example.](https://eval.in/186797)

Comment: +1 but what's the point of keeping a copy of the object inside of `$this->classes` (especially since it gets overwritten)?

Comment: Purely for not needing to define a property for each child class name - keep them in an array instead. No difference between that and `$this->{$class}` if you want to define it for each possible child.

Answer (score 2):

@HAL9000 is right: what you want is not supported. One potential workaround is:

Define the handlers:

```
$typeHandlers = array();
$typeHandlers['song.pause'] = function () {
    echo 'Pause!'; // or whatever...
};
```

Call the appropriate handler:

```
$typeHandlers[$type]();
```